# Nerve functor for symmetric monoidal category

Tags: monoidal-categories, symmetric-monoidal-categories

The nerve $N(\mathsf{C})$ of a category $\mathsf{C}$ can be seen as a geometric realization of it (via n-simplices). This defines a functor $N: \mathsf{Cat} \rightarrow \mathsf{SSet}$ called nerve functor. The nerve functor $N: \mathsf{Cat} \rightarrow \mathsf{SSet}$ is fully and faithful. See porposition 3.11 in [Ref 1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve).

The motivation is to generalize this construction to the case of symmetric monoidal categories. The attempt are in [Ref 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.08963.pdf).

The problem is how to show the functor from the category of small symmetric monoidal categories to the category of copresheaves on $\mathsf{Cau}$ defined in theorem 1.2.1 in [Ref 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.08963.pdf) is fully faithful. The key point is to show for any symmetric monoidal category $\mathsf{S}_1$ and $\mathsf{S}_2$, ${\rm Hom}(\mathsf{S}_1,\mathsf{S}_2)\cong{\rm Hom}(\mathcal{F}_{\mathsf{S}_1},\mathcal{F}_{\mathsf{S}_2})$.

I am currently unable to devise a proof or establish a concrete approach to this point. Hence, I am seeking assistance from anyone who might be able to shed light on this matter. Your guidance and insights would be greatly appreciated.